# Overloading the increment operator for an iterator class

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, increment

I've been attempting to overload the ++ operator to move an iterator through a list, but I keep getting Error   C2460   'List::Iterator::++': uses 'List::Iterator'

```
template <typename E>
class List : public SLinkedList<E> {

public:
// NOTE THE DIFFERENT LETTER – IT IS ONLY USED HERE! 
// Use E everywhere else! m
// For a nested class, methods are declared and defined *INSIDE*
// the class declaration.
template <typename I>
class Iterator {
public:
    // Give List access to Iterator private fields.
    friend class List<E>;

    // These are the minimum methods needed.
    E operator* {nodePosition->elem}; //dereference the iterator and return a value
    Iterator<E> operator++ {nodePosition = nodePosition->next};  //increment the iterator
    Iterator<E> operator-- {
        nodePosition = nodePosition->prev;
    }  //decrement the iterator
    bool operator==(const Iterator<E> p)  { 
        return (nodePosition == p)
    }  //test equality of iterators
    bool operator!=(const Iterator<E> p) {
        return (nodePosition != p)
    }   //test inequality of iterators


private:
    // Constructors & destructor here since only want List class to access.

    // List constructor called from List::begin(). Use initializer list or
    // create class copy constructor and assignment overload.
    Iterator(const List<E>* sl) : llist(sl) {
        nodePosition = sl->head;
    }

    // Class fields.
    const List<E>* llist;     //give Iterator class a handle to the list
    Node<E>* nodePosition;  //abstracted position is a pointer to a node

}; /** end Iterator class **/

   /* The Iterator class is now fully defined. The rest of these
   statements must go AFTER the Iterator class or the compiler
   won’t have complete information about their data types.
   */

   // REQUIRED: While not necessary for the code to work, my test suite needs
   // this defined. Create a less cumbersome name for Iterator<E>. Use 
   // anywhere you would have used List<E>::Iterator<E> in class List. Allows 
   // this syntax in main() -- List<int>::iterator instead of List<int>::Iterator<int>.
typedef typename List<E>::Iterator<E> iterator;

/***    All method declarations and fields for the List class go here.
Any method that returns an iterator must be defined here.
***/
iterator begin() const {  //return an iterator of beginning of list
                          // Call iterator constructor with pointer to List that begin() was 
                          // called with.
    return iterator(this);
}
E back();
E pop_back();
void push_back(const E e);
```

}; /** end List class declaration **/

Comment: Your `operator++` and `operator--` and `operator*` are missing a return statement. and missing the parameter list. They all have the wrong return type too

Comment: If I include a return statement I get syntax error: return. I did change the return type to Iterator<E>&

Comment: You are missing/adding semi-colons everywhere too. Your return statements need them, and your methods do not need a trailing one (ie. `{ ... };`)

Comment: You need a return statement, *and* fix your syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The following method definitions are malformed:

```
E operator* {nodePosition->elem}; //dereference the iterator and return a value
Iterator<E> operator++ {nodePosition = nodePosition->next};  //increment the iterator
Iterator<E> operator-- {
    nodePosition = nodePosition->prev;
}  //decrement the iterator
```

Even though none of these methods need parameters, the `()` is still required. The compiler is probably seeing them as variable definitions of some sort and letting things continue long enough to get the error message OP is reporting.

```
E operator*() {nodePosition->elem}; //dereference the iterator and return a value
Iterator<E> operator++() {nodePosition = nodePosition->next};  //increment the iterator
Iterator<E> operator--() {
    nodePosition = nodePosition->prev;
}  //decrement the iterator
```

They are also all state that they return a value, but none of the function bodies do. There is a lot more work required here before this code will function.